# Laravel loop through all columns

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach

Can somebody help me make my code more efficient... I am trying to display champions from each year and I can't figure out how to loop through each column of years and instead am going through year by year and displaying records and champions, which I feel is criminally inefficient..... here is my controller and view.

Controller

```
$seasonOnes= TeamRank::select('am')
->where('2016', 1)
->get();
$seasonTwos= TeamRank::select('am')
->where('2015', 1)
->get();
```

View

```
@if($seasonTwos)
@foreach($seasonTwos as $seasonTwo)
    <strong>2015 Winner</strong>
    {{$seasonTwo->am}}
@endforeach
@endif
```

And I have one of these for each loops for each season in my database where each column is a year. To be clear, my code IS working, but I feel like there has to be a way to loop through each column. Can I set a variable to an array and have it loop through that at various where statements?

Comment: you snippet doesn't make sense??? specially the where clause. You are selecting some column from TeamRank model where (what equals what)??? can you clear it up?? like your table description??

Comment: Where is the season column or year, I didn't create the database, but each column is a season with rankings 1-63 based on where the team finished that year, so "where->'2016', '1' means that they finished first in that group... I am hoping to loop through each column of seasons and pull the team with the "1" ranking aka the champion

Comment: so 2016 2015 is your column names ?

Comment: yes, 2005-2016 are the column names

Comment: @Supun Praneeth Does that information help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you looking for but this might help other users.

> You should never use data as column name.

in your code the year is a column so every year, you have to add extra column or in another words it's not countable. so never create a table that easy to read by human but not for the computer. I guess you table design look like this:

```
am     | 2005  | 2006 | 2007
name1  |  1    |  0   |  1
name2  |  0    |  1   |  0
name3  |  0    |  0   |  0
```

This is my recommended design:

```
am    | year 
name1 | 2005
name2 | 2006
name1 | 2007
```

Or

```
am    | year  | win
name1 | 2005  | 1
name2 | 2006  | 1
name3 | 2007  | 0
```

so let's say you created using last method, then you can access data like this:

***Controller***

```
$seasons= TeamRank::where('win', 1)->get();
```

***View***

```
@foreach($seasons as $win)
    <strong>{{$win->year}} Winner</strong>
    {{$win->am}}
@endforeach
```

See easy right

so about you question, I think this is the best way to do that:

***Controller***

```
$years = [2006,2007,2008];
$YearsWins = [];

foreach($years as $year){
 $YearsWins[$year] =  TeamRank::select('am')
  ->where($year, 1)
  ->first()->am;     
}
```

***View***

```
 @foreach($YearsWins as $year=>$name)        
        <strong>{{$year}} Winner</strong>
        {{$name}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: $seasons =( [ 2005, 2006,2007])

               $seasonWins=[];

               foreach($seasons as $season) {
                   $seasonWins[$season]=GameData::select('team')
                  ->where('win', '1')
                   ->where('stage', 'R16')
                   ->where('round', 'final')
                   ->where('elimination', '1')
                   ->where('year', $season)
                   ->get();
               }

I used this to get: [{"team":"06 France"}], how do I get these brackets to disappear

Comment: you mean $seasonWins return  [{"team":"06 France"}] ??

Comment: I figured it out, in the comment above, get(); need to be value('team); and you get jus the team without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
$champions = DB::table('your_table_name')
            ->groupBy('year_column_name')
            ->having('ranking_column_name', '=', 1)
            ->get();
```

you can do something like above, then @foreach($champions as $c) and rest.

Comment: I will try this immediately... I did upvote this but don't have enough points for the public upvote yet, sorry

Comment: This won't work because my columns are my years, 2005, 2006, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in your controller,

```
getAttributes()
```

example

```
TeamRank::where('id',2)->first()->getAttributes();
```

This will return array of selected row attributes as they are stored in table.